# Socioboard-login/signup error" Sorry some Error occurred , Please reload the page"

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in a existing project that has a socioboard setup. I have been assigned to solve the login/sign up issue. The project is remotely hosted. The issue when someone tries to sign up with google,facebook or other social medias it is displaying "some errors occurred, reload the page". sign in email is also giving a red image notification. In the console it giving the following errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
plugins/custom/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
login:611 Uncaught ReferenceError: reset is not defined
    at login:611:45
(anonymous) @ login:611
login:1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #emailId:
<input class=​"form-control form-control-solid h-auto py-7 rounded-lg font-size-h6" type=​"text" name=​"email" id=​"emailId" autocomplete=​"off" placeholder=​"Email">​ <input class=​"form-control form-control-solid h-auto py-7 rounded-lg font-size-h6" type=​"text" name=​"emailId" id=​"emailId" autocomplete=​"off" placeholder=​"Email">​
plugins.bundle.js:3841 jQuery.Deferred exception: SBAppSettings is not defined ReferenceError: SBAppSettings is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://smm.grit0.com/js/main.js:328:16)
    at mightThrow (http://smm.grit0.com/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js:3557:29)
    at process (http://smm.grit0.com/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js:3625:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ plugins.bundle.js:3841
process @ plugins.bundle.js:3629
plugins.bundle.js:3850 Uncaught ReferenceError: SBAppSettings is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:328:16)
    at mightThrow (plugins.bundle.js:3557:29)
    at process (plugins.bundle.js:3625:12)
(anonymous) @ main.js:328
mightThrow @ plugins.bundle.js:3557
process @ plugins.bundle.js:3625
build/js/utils.js?1613236686837:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
intlTelInput.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.